# List EBS VolumeID and Instance ID in AWS Query

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I need to list EBS VolumeID and the instance that it's attached to using the aws cli. This is the line I used:

```
 aws ec2 describe-volumes --output text --query 'Volumes[*].{VolumeID:VolumeId, Instance:InstanceId}' | head -5
None    vol-07210e47
None    vol-743d1234
None    vol-933d12d3
None    vol-493c1309
None    vol-1e3b145e
```

For some reason the instance IDs are showing as none. When the unfiltered output of the command shows that they're there:

```
 aws ec2 describe-volumes | head -25
{
    "Volumes": [
        {
            "AvailabilityZone": "us-east-1d", 
            "Attachments": [
                {
                    "AttachTime": "2013-09-05T15:17:39.000Z", 
                    "InstanceId": "i-c28e20ae", 
                    "VolumeId": "vol-07210e47", 
                    "State": "attached", 
                    "DeleteOnTermination": false, 
                    "Device": "/dev/sda1"
                }
            ],
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not querying into Attachments.  This worked for me:

```
aws ec2 describe-volumes --output text --query 'Volumes[*].Attachments[].{VolumeID:VolumeId,InstanceID:InstanceId}'
```

This is a good link:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/controlling-output.html

Comment: If I want to list volume size, volume type, volume status and associated instance-id, then how do i query? Can you please tell me?